# Range where a function is positive

Tags: r, function

I have a function

```
function(y,mu=mu0,lsig=lsig0) {
  res = exp(2*y)/(1+exp(y))^2 * 1/sqrt(2*pi)/exp(lsig) * exp(-(y-mu)^2/2/exp(lsig)^2)
  return(res)
}
```

where mu and lsig is two parameters which differ for each iteration
and I want to find a range where its value is positive.

Actually, this function is always positive but appears as zero if it is very close to zero.

```
mu0 = -6
lsig0 = -2

> fun1(-12:10)
 [1]  0.000000e+00 3.304189e-306 1.230744e-198 8.903329e-115  1.250678e-54
 [6]  3.409942e-18  1.802249e-05  1.840279e-16  3.597724e-51 1.315197e-109
[11] 8.485366e-192 8.567881e-298  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[16]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[21]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

Here, the smallest and largest integer that makes fun1 positive is -11 and -1 respectively.

First, I can try something like

```
> fun1(-12:10) > 0
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But I don't know how to retrieve -11 and -1 from this TRUE/FALSE vector.

Secondly, even though I know how to do so, I don't know how wide the vector (e.g. -12:10) should be for each case.

Answer (score 1):

This may be round about but worked when I tried it:

```
range.test=-12:10
test.output = fun1(range.test) > 0
output.values = which(test.output == TRUE)
final = range.test[output.values]
```

You can then do max(final) and min(final) to get your range.